# Streaming tweets with kafka and without it to analyze in Hive

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, streaming, apache-nifi, tweets

I wanna do a project where I stream some tweets to analyze them in Hive, all this process have to be done in HDF/NiFi. The project must be scalable.
I saw in the Cloudera site that people adopt two different flow strategist.

1.) Get the tweets ---> Put them into the HDFS ---> analyze with Hive

2.) Get the tweets ---> Stream with Kafka(publish/consumer) ---> Put them into the HDFS ---> Analyze with Hive

SO, my question is what's the difference? the first strategy isn't scalable?
Which strategy would you follow?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your maintenance burden.

Hadoop, YARN, Kafka, and Nifi are all isolated services that require lots of tuning and configuration. Every component except for the Twitter ingestion is scalable independently.

You can use Kafka as a type of buffer in front of HDFS for batching and processing tweets before landing in any filesystem. In addition, you can later stream tweets into Elasticsearch or Solr for searching rather than bulk analysis in Hadoop

For faster queries, use Presto, Kudu, Spark, or Impala rather than Hive